# Mock void method's try catch block and catch exception using EasyMock or Mockito

Tags: java, junit, mocking, mockito, easymock

I have a code something like this and I want to write a unit test to below code, completely . I am able to hit try part of the code but couldn't figure out how I can test the catch exception part.

```
public class CacheUpdateTask implements Runnable {

    private WarehouseCache cache;

    private static final int EXPONENTIAL_MULTIPLIER = 100;

    private static final int MAXIMUM_TIME_LIMIT = 5;

    public CacheUpdateTask(
            final WarehouseCache cache) {
        this.cache = cache;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        LOG.info("Requesting warehouse mapping from AService and updating the cache.");
        final Callable<Void> updateCache =
                new Callable<Void>() {
                    @Override
                    public Void call() throws Exception {
                        cache.updateWarehouseCountryCodeCache();
                        return null;
                    }
                };
        final Retryer<Void> retryer = RetryerBuilder.<Void>newBuilder()
                .retryIfException()
                .withWaitStrategy(WaitStrategies.exponentialWait(EXPONENTIAL_MULTIPLIER, MAXIMUM_TIME_LIMIT,
                        TimeUnit.MINUTES))
                .withStopStrategy(StopStrategies.neverStop())
                .build();
        try {
            retryer.call(updateCache); // this is also a void method, so no return here
        } catch (ExecutionException | RetryException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            LOG.error(e);
            LOG.error("Exception when refreshing the cache.");
        }
        LOG.info("Cache has been updated.");
    }
}
```

#### Points to note

- Here the retryer is configured to neverStop. Whenever an exception is raised on call `retryer.call(updateCache);`  retryer actually retries. So in try block when `retryer.call(updateCache)` throws an exception, execution  doesn't flow to catch block and just keeps trying.
- I tried to mimic code in try block to throw some exception in multiple ways, but it is never invoking the code in catch. Below code is my last attempt before creating this question. In most of my attempts tests are succeeding but I am never ending up testing the catch block
- Below code runs successfully, but it is actually not hitting `catch block` based on code coverage test.

```
@Test (expected = ExecutionException.class)
    public void test_UpdateCacheFOServiceRunException() throws Exception {
        WarehouseCacheFOServiceUpdateTask mockUpdateTaskFOService;
        WarehouseCache mockClientCache;
        mockUpdateTaskFOService = Mockito.mock(WarehouseCacheFOServiceUpdateTask.class);
        mockClientCache = Mockito.mock(WarehouseCache.class);


        Mockito.doThrow(ExecutionException.class)
                .when(mockClientCache).updateWarehouseCountryCodeCacheFOService();
        //clientCache.updateWarehouseCountryCodeCacheFOService();
        //Mockito.doThrow( ExecutionException.class )
          //      .when(mockUpdateTaskFOService).run();
        mockClientCache.updateWarehouseCountryCodeCacheFOService();
        mockUpdateTaskFOService.run();

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your test is incorrect to expect this

```
@Test(expected = ExecutionException.class)
```

If you look back at your code, you will see that you catch, log and swallow that exception. It is never rethrown, so your test should not expect it.

Other than that, your test looks broadly correct. You have no means to make any meaningful assertions, since the logger is static.

The following is a bit misleading

```
Mockito.doThrow(ExecutionException.class)
```

since the `ExecutionException` you are trying to catch an exception which `Retryer` is supposed to wrap the original exception with. What you are currently simulating is an `ExecutionException` wrapping an `ExecutionException`. It will work for the sake of your test, but is not realistic. I would throw a generic `Exception.class` (which will then be wrapped).

---

There is a slight bug in your code which will cause misleading logging. This line will execute even if an exception was thrown, caught, and logged.

```
LOG.info("Cache has been updated.");
```

You have two choices, you can either put a `return` in the catch, or move the logging line.

```
try {
    retryer.call(updateCache);
    LOG.info("Cache has been updated."); // this
} catch (ExecutionException | RetryException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    LOG.error(e);
    LOG.error("Exception when refreshing the cache.");
    return; // or this
}
```

Comment: Hello Michael, thanks for your explanation. What change do you suggest me to make so that I can hit the catch block and log the exception.